# HTML a href horizontally to section of page (ie, say 9000 pixels wide)

Tags: html, css, hyperlink

I need to load a page in an iframe and the only content I want to show is located far to the right of that page.

Is it even possible to do this?

http://www.example.com/tags#top for example to my knowledge only links vertically (ie up and down) where as I need to scroll to the right.

Comment: You'll need JavaScript for something like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the `scrollTo()` method:

```
function scrollWin() {
    window.scrollTo(500, 0);
}
```

This scrolls 500 pixels to the right.

Comment: This will only work if the `iframe` is sourced from the same website. jQuery, however supports the id attribute on the load function: `$(".load_to").load("load_from #id")` http://jquery.com